# In what way does a new ECS Fargate service not satisfy the task definition's required capabilities?

Tags: amazon-ecs, fargate, amazon-efs

When creating a new AWS ECS service using a Fargate task, in the AWS Console wizard, it fails with the following error:

```
Failed creation of Service
Service creation failed: The specified platform does not satisfy the task definition’s required capabilities.
```

The service launch type is set to `FARGATE` and the Platform version is set to `LATEST`. The task is attempting to mount an AWS EFS filesystem for persistent storage (introduced in version 1.4.0 of the platform).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design because AWS have yet to upgrade LATEST to point to v1.4.0 (as per 2020-06-23, see [AWS ECS Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/platform_versions.html#platform-version-considerations)). Set the service platform version explicitly to `1.4.0` (instead of LATEST).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't tell the exact error message, however in my case,

I was using firelens log driver with S3 configuration type. Since Fargate only supports local file at this point, I got the same error message. Once I changed it to local file in the task definition json, it proceeded further.

Comment: ty, it wasn't the problem in this case but could be helpful for someone else.